# Import dates in BC into postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I want to import the data of the following format (in a csv file) into postgres:

```
   ('string1', 'string2', 'string3', 1999-10-10,2000-10-10)
```

Here column1, column2, column3 are of type string and column4, column5 are of type date. My problem is, apart from normal dates like '1999-10-10'. I also want dates in "BC" to be imported into postgres, but I am not getting how to achieve the same. Can someone please help me with this?

Eg. I want dates of the following format to be imported into postgres:

```
  ('string1', 'string2', 'string3', 199-10-10 BC, 200-10-10 BC)
```

Is it possible to important csv fies with dates in BC as well as AD into postgres. If yes, can someone please help me with this as I am a complete novice at postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html):

> Valid input for the time stamp types consists of the concatenation of a date and a time, followed by an optional time zone, followed by an optional AD or BC.
>
> Date and time input is accepted in almost any reasonable format, including ISO 8601, SQL-compatible, traditional POSTGRES, and others.

And, **most important in your case**:

> Remember that any date or time literal input needs to be enclosed in single quotes, like text strings.

So you need to quote datetime strings in the CSV, e.g. `'199-10-10 BC'`.

Comment: So is ('string1', 'string2', 'string3', '199-10-10 BC', '200-10-10 BC') a correct input format can I import it directly into postgres

Comment: @JannatArora: exactly.